# ether from json file

Tags: ether, wallets, ethereum-classic

I have a json file with ether created before fork. Now I want to sell ETC without moving ETH. My question is how to do it properly? 
What if I'll restore file into ETC wallet and spend it. Is possible to restore the same file into ETH wallet again?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid replay attacks, isn't it a better solution to move the ETH funds first completely to another wallet before dealing with ETC? Or would a split be impossible after all (or some) ETH are spent from that pre fork json-file?

Comment: There's no need to split ETH and ETC into separate accounts if one is using EIP155-compatible wallet software. You can split any time you want (provided, of course, you have enough ether to pay for transactions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! ETH Json file is already imported into Mist/Geth. Running a second instance of ETC Mist Node would double local storage needs and weakens security (same private key for both wallets). Since Myetherwallet supports ETC (and EIP155 btw.) and you say splitting is possible at any time: Wouldn't it still be most secure to move (todays) more valuable ETH to a new Mist wallet and import the Json file afterwards into Myetherwallet? That would be more of a "moving" than "splitting" approach and enables independent access of ETHs and ETCs without sharing keys over multiple wallets

Comment: If by moving you mean sending, rather than importing, yes, that makes some sense. It makes sense if you don't trust EIP155's ability to prevent replay attacks or your ability to keep your keys secure (and thus want to minimize exposure when using one chain or the other). However, if you have two keys, keep in mind you now need to secure (and back up) TWO keys which may be harder than securing one. IMHO, the best option is to use the same wallet software for both things (thus reducing your attack surface area). AFAIK, there's no reason to use Mist for one and and MEW for the other.

Comment: Yes, correct. With moving I meant sending. I trust my ability to keep my keys secure. But I do not trust applications and their bugs. I've read here https://steemit.com/ethereum/@pauls/ethereum-fork-step-by-step-guide-to-safely-splitting-your-eth-etc that it isn't advised to run both on Mist at the same time. Thus my idea of using 2 wallets.

Comment: Actually, I take that back... there is a reason to trust Mist for one and not the other; an offline wallet is less convenient, but more secure.

Comment: Ah... I use Parity and two chains. You can change the data directory to allow you to switch between chains and even use both simultaneously. Same goes for `geth`, used by Mist. OTOH, there's another reason to use two wallets: I wouldn't trust myself to not get the two accounts confused!

Comment: absolutely! Great conversation! Thanks for your thoughts!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have both ETH and ETC. As long as replay protection [is implemented on both chains](https://github.com/ethereumclassic/README/issues/3#issuecomment-304044381), you can initialize both wallets from one keystore file and use them independently, e.g., via [Myetherwallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) (choose ETC or ETH in the top right corner).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it's a little bit different from bitcoin fork, where is recommended to move your BTC to a new address before you spend your BCH.